# Hierarchical Filtering in tableau

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have a filter that includes cities and I have another filed that is region and each city goes with a region. For example:

```
New York -> RegionID = 1  
Seattle -> RegionID = 2  
Boston -> RegionID = 2  
Nashville -> RegionID = 3
```

Now I want to filter my sheets and dashboard with cities but I want this to be hierarchy that user can select `RegionID` and Cities corresponding with that reagion appears to select from.

How can I do such thing?

Answer (score 0):

Tableau can do this with "Values from Hierarchy" in the filter options.  In fact, this is the default behavior now.  https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/filtering.htm#set-options-for-filter-card-interaction-and-appearance

There is also an Extension that can display this in a tree view.  https://github.com/tableau/extension-hierarchy-navigator-sandboxed